# Insert 4 figures in a square like structure

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I want to insert 4 figures in structure of a square i.e. in two rows and two columns, the structure I talk about is given in the image below;

[image]

Please help me with piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{a}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{b}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{c}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{d}
\end{center}
\caption{ 4 figures}
```

Comment: I got a 'caption outside float' error.

Comment: @StatsSorceress the code shown was answering the question about floats so intended as the content of a float, eg `figure` but in general it's better to ask a new question rather than leave a comment on an old answer.

Comment: thanks, but I wasn't trying to ask a new question. Sorry I was unclear! I was trying to recommend that the code be put between `\begin{figure}` and `end{figure}` for completeness. You're right, that was vague and I apologize.

Comment: I had to put graphics I wanted next to each other on the same line.  If there was a line break in between, then the graphics wouldn't sit next to each other.

Comment: @JakeIreland they will go on one line if they fit, note a newline typesets as an inter-word space so you can not get 4 images that are .25\textwidth and three spaces all on the same line, you need to not have the space or make the images small enough to fit