# Arrange 8 photos automatically on one page

Tags: graphics, posters

I'm printing posters for a birthday with pictures. Im putting 8 photos on a1 plot. currently all i do is:

```
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1-4.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1-2.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
```

4 times and adjust the size of the pictures manually to allow 8 pictures on a page. is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Please give a full but minimal code. Do you need captions? And have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171576 There are quite a lot of posts on this topic if you just google that.